# Rename an image during the uploading in php

Tags: php

Am trying to rename an image during upload i know i am met to put the function rand() and end() but i just do not know where to put it here is my code below

**php / html section**

```
if (isset($_POST['uploadimage'])) {
    list($typed) = $_FILES['images']['type'];
    if(!ereg("image",$typed)){
    echo  "<div class='msg1'>File is not an image or field is empty</div>";
        }else{
            $pixsname = $_FILES['images']['name'];
            while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['images']['name'])){

if(!empty($value)) {
$pixsname = $value;
$add = "./img/venues/$pixsname";   

            copy($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $add);
chmod("$add",0777);
            }
                $image = new Image();
                $image->load("$add");
                $image->resize(652,300);
                $image->save("$add"); 
}

echo  "<div class='msg1'>Image profile has been updated</div>";
        }
}



form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="loginform" >
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000000">
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="fileField" class="field_ss"/> 
<?php echo $pix; ?> 
<input type="submit"  name="uploadimage" value="Upload Image"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: please read http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$pixsname = $value;
```

with

```
$pixsname = 'The_New_Name_Of_Your_Picture';
```

Comment: I suggest you to read his question again: ".. but i just do not know where to put it here is my code below". I think I told him exactly where to put it. So much hate on SO, why?

Comment: I did this $pixsname = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($value); it upload the image, rename it BUT THE IMAGE IS NOT DISPLAYING I note the the .jpg is missing in the image

Comment: Oh ofcourse, my bad. You need to add the file extension to the name of the image. If you are working with only one filetype, do it like this `$pixsname = rand(1,99999) . '.jpg';` or what's your file type instead of '.jpg'. If you are using more than one file type you can do it like this `$pixsname = rand(1,99999).strrchr($value, ".");`